# iOS - Allow all users to find map pins near them

Tags: ios, location

I'm making an iOS app where users are able to place a pin (CLLocation) on a map and all other users within x miles of that point will be able to see it on a map. How can I do this?

Comment: You are asking how to share data between many instances of an application. That's likely to be a very broad question and it's hard to know what a good answer would look like.

Comment: I want to build functionality like what Anywall (https://parse.com/tutorials/anywall) has, except I don't want to use Parse. Essentially, instead of having map pins restricted to individual users, I want all other users to see a pin once a user places it on a map.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking "how do I implement my own API backend for an app?" Specific solutions are the subject of many books, classes, and years of experience. Choosing the "right" solution is an even broader question. What sort of answer are you looking for?

Comment: I'm asking where I can start looking. How do apps like Uber or Tinder find everyone near a user's location?

Answer (score 1):

1) User places a pin on the map -> pin placing function sends a message to a server with latitude, longitude, and the annotation name.

2) Server checks what users are within the radius -> Sends silent notification to users.

3) Local apps drop a pin.

OR

2) Server sends a silent notification to all users (containing the latitude, longitude).

3) Local instances of app decide whether or not to drop a pin on the location.

Basically you have a fair bit of choice here - should users need to constantly update servers with their location, and only the relevant users get sent a notification? Or do you want all users to receive a notification and the app to decide if a notification should be dropped.

Answer (score 1):

A simplistic view of one possible solution could have three major components:

1. The client-side app which allows users to view and place pins.
2. A server-side app which receives locations from and sends pins to many clients.
3. A database which stores all of the known pins.

The question then suggests two sequences of interest:

Creating a pin:

1. A user creates a pin on a client app. The client app sends a description of that pin to the server (this is often an HTTP POST request but there are many options).
2. The server receives this request, validates that it understands the description of the pin and that the client has permission to create it, converts it into a format convenient for storage in a database and sends it to the database.
3. The database adds the new pin information to its list of known pins.
4. The server responds to the client's request with a "success" message confirming that the pin was saved.

Viewing pins:

1. A client app needs to show nearby pins (because a user launched the app, or switched to a map view, or the app received a notification, or whatever). The client sends a request to the server asking which asks for all visible pins and which includes the client's location. (You can decide if the client also get's to define what distance counts as "nearby" or not.) (If creating a pin used an HTTP POST then this is probably a HTTP GET but again there are many options.)
2. The server receives this request, determines if it should share pin information with this user, and if so constructs a query which will obtain all "nearby" pins from the database.
3. The database responds to this query with information about 0 to many pins.
4. The server converts the database representation of these pins into a format the client app can understand and sends a response containing these pins. (As the set of pins becomes very large this may become more complicated; the server might only return some of the nearby pins and information about how many more were not included, the client could then get another "page" of results in a second request.)

There are many decisions to make along the way and many tools to choose from to build all of these pieces. There are many programming languages you could use to write the server-side component (and many frameworks written in those languages which try to make building certain types of web applications easier). There are many data formats you might use to exchange information and many databases you might use to store these data (some of which have built in support for the sort of geolocation math you would need to determine which pins are "near" a given latitude and longitude).